# HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload is always null in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to create a project in aps.net mvc 5, but I can't save an image in my local directory... The attribute: (HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload) of my entity  (Perfil), is always null **translating to English: Profile = Perfil**

Can someone help me please?

. My Entity:

```
[Table("Perfil")]
public class Perfil
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int idPerfil { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Usuario")]
    public int idUsuario { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Genero")]
    public int idGenero { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Descrição:")]
    public string descricao { get; set; }

    public string linkMultimidia { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public virtual Genero Genero { get; set; }
}
```

}

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "idPerfil,idUsuario,idGenero,descricao,linkMultimidia,fotoPerfil")] Perfil perfil)
    {
        var validImageTypes = new string[]
        {
            "image/gif",
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/pjpeg",
            "image/png"
        };

        if (perfil.ImageUpload == null || perfil.ImageUpload.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "This field is required");
        }
        else if (!validImageTypes.Contains(perfil.ImageUpload.ContentType))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "Please choose either a GIF, JPG or PNG image.");
        }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (perfil.ImageUpload != null && perfil.ImageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var uploadDir = "~/Imagens";
                    var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(uploadDir), perfil.ImageUpload.FileName);
                    var imageUrl = Path.Combine(uploadDir, perfil.ImageUpload.FileName);
                    perfil.ImageUpload.SaveAs(imagePath);
                    perfil.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
                }

                    rep.IncluirPerfil(perfil);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        ViewBag.idGenero = new SelectList(db.Generos, "idGenero", "nomeGenero", perfil.idGenero);
        ViewBag.idUsuario = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "idUsuario", "nome", perfil.idUsuario);
        return View(perfil);
    }
```

My Create View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "PerfilController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
             <div class="col-md-10">   
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUpload)
              </div>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageUpload, new { type = "file" })
            }            
      </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried other solutions, but continued null...

Comment: not sure if your code examples are correct.. but your submit isn't even inside your form and `ImageUpload` is not in your `[Bind(Include)]` list

Comment: might help if you post your entire Create view

Comment: Not only is you submit button outside the form, you specifically exclude the file from binding in your `[Bind]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The submit button must be inside `using` block:

```
<div class="form-group">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUpload)
        </div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageUpload, new {type = "file"})
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Also add `ImageUpload` to Bind list:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "idPerfil,idUsuario,idGenero,descricao,linkMultimidia,fotoPerfil, ImageUpload")] Perfil perfil)
```

**One more thing**, You can use `Exclude` instead of `Include` in your case.

Comment: saw the same thing but it almost looks like he might have 2 forms and the ImageUpload form is inside another form..

Comment: Yep, By the way, you need something to post the form inside that `using` block.

Comment: Tnks Sirwan, but it's still null... In my Controller, the *perfil.ImageUpload == null*

Answer (score 0):

I solved!

**Entity:**

```
public string photoPath{ get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "idPerfil,idUsuario,idGenero,descricao,linkMultimidia,photoPath")] Perfil perfil)
{
    string filename = perfil.photoPath;

    var uploadDir = "~/Imagens";
    var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(uploadDir), filename);
    var imageUrl = Path.Combine(uploadDir, filename);
    perfil.photoPath = imageUrl;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        rep.IncluirPerfil(perfil);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.idGenero = new SelectList(db.Generos, "idGenero", "nomeGenero", perfil.idGenero);
    ViewBag.idUsuario = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "idUsuario", "nome", perfil.idUsuario);
    return View(perfil);
}
```

**Create View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.photoPath, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.photoPath, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.photoPath)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which is exactly what Sirwan Afifi's answer explains (only better) so why have you added this instead of accepting that answer?